# How to get more informations about this device?

Tags: rhel, disk-usage, udev, devices, storage

If I only have the following information, how can I figure out what this device is ?

```
# df -Ph
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1
```

I know that "sd" are SCSI disk, "hd" are IDE disk etc. So what about "cciss" ?

What other command lines can I use to get more details about this device? 
I'm using RHEL systems.

Comment: `man cciss` to read the manual.

Comment: I tired it. No manual for cciss.

Comment: In fact, my question is more general. I took this cciss device as an example but my question is more about how to find out about a device in /dev that I would'nt know? What native commands can I use to find out more about this unknown device (to find out what vendor it is, what type it is etc.).

Comment: Install the package(s) that provide the manual pages, and read those. I'm sorry, but since I'm not on Red Hat I don't quite know what packages those might be. The manual is also available at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/cciss.4.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a drive on a SmartArray controller (controller 0, drive 0, partition 1). You’ll find more information in the kernel’s [`cciss`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/blockdev/cciss.txt) documentation, and you can use the [CCISS Utilities](http://cciss.sourceforge.net/#cciss_utils) to get more details about the drive.

If you’re interested in the actual drive details rather than the RAID information from the HBA, you can also use [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org/):

```
smartctl -a -d cciss,0 /dev/cciss/c0d0
```

will show all the available information from the first drive.

Comment: thanks but what I'm really asking is how can I find out the final information you gave me. Can I do it only using command lines?

Comment: See my update. I don’t currently have an SA HBA to test things with, so I can’t give you example output.